# Show the message of the validator for a hidden field

Tags: java, html, validation, spring-mvc

When I try to validate if a ***hidden*** field is empty or not by **Spring Validator**, the message sent by the validator is ***hidden*** to !! however i want to show it. This is the hidden field :

```
<form:errors path="cinn" Class="errorblock"/>
<input type="hidden" value="${agact.cinn}" name="cinn" />
```

The method of the validator which return the message :

```
public void validate(Object obj, Errors err) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "cinn", "name.required","You have to choose an agent first");
    }
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: I guess you should rethink your design. How do you expect the users can edit a hidden field to fix its value to begin with?

Comment: I fill it automatically, this field will be sent to another page that's why i hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user should not modify that field (unless fiddling with firebug or the like) in the first place so the best bet is to assert that the value is correct and if not, throw an exception (e.g. IllegalStateException) and react to that by showing an error message, e.g.:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String submit(..) {
    if (hidden field is empty) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Missing XXX");
    }
    ....
   return "redirect:success"
}

@ExceptionHandler
public String handle(IllegalStateException e) {
    logger.warn("User attempted to fiddle with POST data");
    return "error";
}
```

Where "error" is a sample view name.

Comment: What do you mean by throw an exception and react to that in the UI ?

Comment: Please which jar should I import for get the logger ? 
this import returns an error for me : import org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.Log_.logger;  @Jukka

Comment: Use e.g. SLF4J with logback.